# What's the difference between Cloud Optimized ASP.Net vNext and the regular version?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linux, mono, asp.net-core

I am extremely excited about the recent developments around the ASP.Net platform, mono and open source and I want to start develop applications (I expect mainly API's for mobile applications but also full websites) that can also run on a Linux server. So I am busy installing everything, programming and reading but one thing I keep bumping into as a side note is the fact that the ASP.Net stack you can run on Mac OS X and Linux has a reduced framework, for example on [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/05/12/the-next-generation-of-net-asp-net-vnext.aspx).

> On .NET vNext (Cloud Optimized)
>
> ....
>
> Uses a smaller set of framework libraries

I am wondering what the full implications are of this, especially for the specific purpose of creating webpages or API's. What libraries aren't available and which are?

Comment: That's going to have everything to do with the development and direction of vNext and its level of maturity. It's just in its infant stages right now. As it matures to a releasable state, this may not even be a concern any more. Even before that happens, I imagine any possible answer to this question will vary at any given time because of the active state of development.

Comment: It ultimately comes down to whatever Mono supports will be supported? There will be no arbitrary line drawn between libraries where one will never be supported and the other will be available?

Comment: Well, Cloud-optimized != Mono. The core difference between cloud-optimized and regular is the latter requires .NET Framework to be installed on the machine and runs inside IIS, while the former has the pieces of the .NET Framework it needs packaged with it and is self-hosted. Whether Mono is used or not for those packaged components is secondary. From what I understand, though, there should be no functional distinction between cloud-optimized and regular. The same app should be able to run either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET vNext (the web framework stack) has basically nothing to do with the cloud optimized runtime, it's just another runtime where it can run on.

Traditionally, the .NET CLR was/is installed machine-wide and updating it is painful as it affects basically every application, which means many developers are stuck with an old CLR/.NET Framework.

That's the reason they introduced the cloud optimized runtime (or CoreCLR), with benefits such as being xcopy deployable and more lightweight in general. You use NuGet packages to fetch only the libraries you need, which includes even things such as `System.Console`.

So in the end, ASP.NET vNext frameworks like MVC or SignalR will run on these runtimes (and Microsoft tests on each of them to ensure they work):

- Desktop CLR (same one we all know since many years)
- Mono
- Cloud-optimized/CoreCLR (the new thing, though based on the work they did with Silverlight)

<s>The cloud-optimized runtime is a Windows-only thing, it doesn't make much sense on Linux/OSX because Mono already gives you most of the benefits like xcopy-deployability. The only thing would be from a feature-completeness point of view, but as I said before Microsoft will test on Mono to make sure it works just fine there.</s>

Sources: https://github.com/aspnet/Testing/issues/34 and http://alxandr.me/2014/06/24/new-blog-vnext-and-some-runting/

**Update Nov, 04:** to add another source that clarifies confusion about CoreCLR on Linux: in the latest standup (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oafQVI4Lx4#t=706) at 11:45 Damin Edwards says:

> CoreCLR runs on Windows. On Linux you use Mono.

**Update Nov, 13:** Microsoft just open-sourced .NET Core and announced they'll be porting it to Linux/Mac: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNET2015NETAsOpenSourceNETOnMacAndLinuxAndVisualStudioCommunity.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems pretty complete. I'll accept it as soon as I've read up a bit more to verify. So the word Cloud is maybe also a bit marketing driven?

Comment: The word Cloud is likely only used for marketing reasons, yes. There's nothing that restricts the CoreCLR from running on a normal Windows machine instead of Azure.

Comment: .net framework blog says, that Mono is only "enabled" for the cloud based variant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/05/12/the-next-generation-of-net-asp-net-vnext.aspx  (scroll down to the table with the comparison). quite confusing

Comment: Still, the term "Cloud Optimized CoreCLR" seems to hint that it is less optimized for the desktop as it is for the cloud (its primary focus is not the desktop). This remindes of the "Client Java Runtime Environment" vs "Server Java Runtime Environment". You can use the Sever JRE for desktop apps but it is less optimal (e.g. because of memory footprint and startup time).

Comment: @bitbonk the focus for ASP.NET5 (and thus CoreCLR, since that is the main driver right now) is the server environment, that's correct, so there might be some minor differences, but I doubt they'll be broadly noticeably. (e.g. you can still NGEN your assemblies to get rid of any JIT delays at startup).